# Al leer una tabla de una página web, ¿cómo se omiten/ignoran aquellas filas que son solo una combinación de celdas usando Pandas en Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, condiciones, dataframe, depuración

Suponga que usted está interesado en guardar la **Tabla del Calendario Económico** de [esta página](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/) **sin la fecha (primer elemento de la tabla)**:

[image: pic1]

Entonces usted escribe el siguiente código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import numpy as np

#the variable that will store the selenium options
opt = Options()
#this allows selenium to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") 
#Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
#execute the chrome driver with the previous conditions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 

def wait_xpath(code): #function to wait for the element to be located by its XPATH
    WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))

#go to investing.com to check the economic calendar
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/')

#wait for the economic calendar table to be located
wait_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table')

#wait for the information to load completely
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr')))

#store the table body information
table_body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody')

#store the cells of the table in a list as WebElements
cells = table_body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')

#actual cell list containing the row in string format
cell_list = []

#column names
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#convert the cells to human readable format and add them to the cell_list
for row in cells[1:]:
    cell_list.append(row.text)
    
#delete the element that appears every 8 elements in the array
cell_list = [word for idx, word in enumerate(cell_list, 1) if idx % 8 != 0]

#reshape the array into an array of unknown arrays and 7 columns
cell_list = np.array(cell_list).reshape(-1, 7).tolist()

#create a dataframe including the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(cell_list, columns=column_names)

#store the volatilities expected (those which are measured with stars)
volatilities_expected = table_body.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')

#actual volatilities list containing the row in string format
volatility_list = []

#convert the volatilities expected to human readable format and add them to the volatility list
for volatility in volatilities_expected:
    volatility_list.append(volatility.get_attribute('title'))
    
#reshape the array into an array of unknown cell and 7 columns
volatility_list = np.array(volatility_list).reshape(-1, 1).tolist()

#add the volatility list to the volatility expected column
df['Volatility expected'] = [v[0] for v in volatility_list]
```

Y después de compilarlo, usted obtiene el siguiente resultado (***para el día de hoy***) :

[image: output1]

Hasta ahora, todo parece estar bien, sin embargo, al intentar el mismo código de arriba sin la sentencia `driver.get('https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/')` para el día de **mañana**:

[image: pic2]

Usted se da cuenta que hay una nueva fila **la cual es sólo una combinación de celdas** que informa que mañana será un día festivo en la India , durante todo el día.

Y, debido a eso, el programa arroja un error:

> **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 312 into shape (7)**

Y la lista que hubiese sido usada para crear la `df` termina rota:

[image: output2]

Entoces, ¿cómo podrían omitirse estos inesperados días festivos que son sólo filas de filas de celdas combinadass con el fin de construir correctamente la `df` como en el primer ejemplo?

Comment: Parece que en la columna Imp., cuando es un día festivo, se coloca "Holiday". Podrías saltar todas las filas donde la columna Imp. es el texto Holiday.

Comment: A mi se me está haciendo dificil hacer funcionar Selenium. Me vendría genial que pusieras una muestra de lo que contiene la variable cells (que por lo que veo tiene las celdas de la tabla) :D

Comment: Pensaba hacer lo que sugeriste en el primer comentario pero no me salió nada de la cabeza, luego decidí incluir esas filas como normalmente lo haría con el resto, y me di cuenta que dicha fila de días festivos tenía en realidad 4 celdas en lugar de las 8 que tienen el resto, así que luego de crear el arreglo, lo recorerría para eliminar todas aquellas filas que no tienen la misma cantidad de celdas `(8)` para luego crear la `df` final @DanteS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, tuve que re hacer el código en su mayoría, el ciclo `for row in row_list:` y la sentencia `volatility_list.remove('')` fueron en esencia la clave para lograr lo que quería:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import numpy as np

#the variable that will store the selenium options
opt = Options()
#this allows selenium to take control of your Chrome Browser in DevTools mode.
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222") 
#Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
#execute the chrome driver with the previous conditions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 

def wait_xpath(code): #function to wait for the element to be located by its XPATH
    WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, code)))

#go to investing.com to check the economic calendar
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/')

#wait for the economic calendar table to be located
wait_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table')

#wait for the information to load completely
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr')))

#count starts at 2
i = 2

#lenght of the table
table_lenght = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr'))
    
#actual row list containing rows as lists in string format
row_list = []

#column names
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#add each row as list to the row_list
while i <= table_lenght:
    cells_in_a_row = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td')
    for index, cell in enumerate(cells_in_a_row, start=0):
        cells_in_a_row[index] = cell.text
    row_list.append(cells_in_a_row)
    i += 1
    
#count removed rows
removed_rows = 0

#delete undesired rows
for row in row_list:
    if len(row) != 8:
        row_list.remove(row)
        removed_rows += 1
    
#delete the last element in every list in the row_list
for row in row_list:
    row.pop()

#reshape the array into an array of unknown arrays and 7 columns
row_list = np.array(row_list).reshape(-1, 7).tolist()

#if there are any cells that have "min", update those cells with the actual time value
for index, x in enumerate(row_list, start=0):
    if "min" in x[0]:
        print(f"Esta fila: {index} {x}")
        y = index + 2 + removed_rows
        actual_time = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[{y}]').get_attribute('data-event-datetime')
        actual_time = actual_time[11:16]
        x[0] = actual_time
        print(f"Fue cambiada por la siguiente: {x} ")

#create a dataframe including the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=column_names)

#store the table body information
table_body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody')

#store the volatilities expected (those which are measured with stars)
volatilities_expected = table_body.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')

#actual volatilities list containing the row in string format
volatility_list = []

#convert the volatilities expected to human readable format and add them to the volatility list
for volatility in volatilities_expected:
    volatility_list.append(volatility.get_attribute('title'))

#remove undesired values
volatility_list.remove('')

#reshape the array into an array of unknown cell and 7 columns
volatility_list = np.array(volatility_list).reshape(-1, 1).tolist()

#add the volatility list to the volatility expected column
df['Volatility expected'] = [v[0] for v in volatility_list]
```

**>> In [2]: df**

**>> Out[2]:**

```
     Time Currency           Volatility expected  ...   Actual Forecast Previous
0   00:30      JPY  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    -0.7%              0.1%
1   02:30      JPY      High Volatility Expected  ...                           
2   05:00      EUR       Low Volatility Expected  ...  -5.052B            1.103B
3   05:00      EUR       Low Volatility Expected  ...   -0.89B            -3.80B
4   06:00      EUR  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    1.50%             2.20%
5   06:00      EUR       Low Volatility Expected  ...    1.90%             2.30%
6   06:00      EUR  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   -27.2B             -4.8B
7   06:30      RUB      High Volatility Expected  ...   20.00%   20.00%   20.00%
8   07:30      INR       Low Volatility Expected  ...  622.28B           631.92B
9   08:00      BRL  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    11.2%    11.4%    11.1%
10  08:00      RUB  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...                           
11  08:30      CAD      High Volatility Expected  ...     2.5%     2.4%    -2.7%
12  08:30      CAD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   13.49B            37.54B
13  08:30      CAD       Low Volatility Expected  ...  -14.42B            21.29B
14  08:30      CAD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...     1.1%              0.9%
15  08:30      CAD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...     3.2%     2.4%    -2.0%
16  10:00      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    -7.2%    -1.0%     6.6%
17  10:00      USD      High Volatility Expected  ...    6.02M    6.10M    6.49M
18  10:00      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...     0.3%     0.3%    -0.5%
19  12:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...                           
20  13:00      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...      524               527
21  13:00      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...      663               663
22  14:00      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...                           
23  15:00      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...                           
24  15:30      GBP  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   -29.1K            -12.5K
25  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...     2.2K              2.5K
26  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...    19.0K             31.8K
27  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...   507.2K            498.0K
28  15:30      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   341.8K            361.7K
29  15:30      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   261.8K            274.4K
30  15:30      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    19.0K             26.6K
31  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...  -146.6K           -138.4K
32  15:30      USD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   102.2K            127.7K
33  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...    51.6K             52.3K
34  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...   217.6K            216.6K
35  15:30      USD       Low Volatility Expected  ...    10.9K             12.6K
36  15:30      CAD       Low Volatility Expected  ...    17.7K              7.6K
37  15:30      CHF       Low Volatility Expected  ...    -5.2K             -9.7K
38  15:30      AUD  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   -44.9K            -78.2K
39  15:30      BRL  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    44.2K             50.5K
40  15:30      JPY  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...   -62.3K            -55.9K
41  15:30      NZD       Low Volatility Expected  ...     3.7K            -12.4K
42  15:30      RUB  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...     7.5K              7.8K
43  15:30      EUR  Moderate Volatility Expected  ...    18.8K             58.8K

[44 rows x 7 columns]
```